# how to calculate percentage of losers by level

Tags: sql, database, data-analysis

| id | event | level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | level_started | 1 |
| 1 | level_completed | 1 |
| 1 | level_started | 2 |
| 1 | level_failed | 2 |
| 2 | level_started | 1 |
| 2 | level_completed | 1 |
| 2 | level_started | 2 |
| 2 | level_failed | 2 |
| 4 | level_started | 1 |
| 4 | level_completed | 1 |
| 4 | level_started | 2 |
| 4 | level_failed | 2 |
| 5 | level_started | 1 |
| 5 | level_completed | 1 |
| 5 | level_started | 2 |
| 5 | level_failed | 2 |
| 3 | level_started | 1 |
| 3 | level_completed | 1 |
| 3 | level_started | 2 |
| 3 | level_failed | 2 |

should output the values:

| level | loss_rate (in percentages) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |

loss rate is when the level in the event column is failed

I am new to sql, please help me

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.

```
create table table1 (
  id integer, 
  event varchar(30), 
  level integer
  );
  
insert into table1 values 
(1, 'level_started', 1), 
(1, 'level_completed', 1), 
(1, 'level_started', 2), 
(1, 'level_failed', 2), 
(2, 'level_started', 1), 
(2, 'level_completed', 1), 
(3, 'level_started', 1), 
(3, 'level_completed', 1), 
(3, 'level_started', 2), 
(3, 'level_completed', 2);
```

---

```
select level, 
 sum(case when event = 'level_failed' then 1 else 0 end) / 
 sum(case when event = 'level_started' then 1 else 0 end) as fail_rate
from table1
group by level
order by level;
```

| level | fail_rate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.0000 |
| 2 | 0.5000 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jRok9QvqnjwXFi8oesLm9/0)

Comment: is it in percentage?

Comment: It's a rate. Just multiply by 100 to get %. So change to `* 100 as fail_pct`